# Choosing Canadian province for studying GIS and finding professional opportunities

Tags: transportation, canada, business

I have a Business Administration degree and a Logistics MBA. My final project was a case study of efficiency improvements through ArcGIS routes in a local road transportation company. Suddenly I fell in love with GIS.

I actually live in Brazil, but I want to **study GIS in Canada** and, who knows, **find a job opportunity** to take my career to a next level. I'd like to stay in **British Columbia** or **Nova Scotia** because of the weather, more similar to Brazil. Both offer top rated programs.

- In BC: BCIT, Okonagan, Selkirk College, SFU and VIU
- In NS: NSCC (COGS)

I understand that BC offers more programs and more job opportunities than NS. The only reason I ask this question is because a cousin of mine is coincidentally immigrating to Halifax, NS. She also told me that Nova Scotia province has encouraging policies for international students and workers, specially in these areas.

Should I count on **BC's hotter job market** or on **NS's conveniences**?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I have specific knowledge here, but I'd say you're probably right with BC's job market being a bit more promising than Nova Scotia's. Here's a real quick breakdown of some provincial economic indicators from Statistics Canada's most recent data (not specific to the GIS industry but gives you an idea of where they're at currently) Although there is generally less unemployment and more housing starts in BC, things typically cost less in Nova Scotia.

[image: Canadian Economic Indicators]

Especially since your plans involve education, I'd say go where you want to go. If it were me, having family nearby would probably outweigh the economic edge of BC.

Answer (score 1):

As graduate of COGS, I would say that you shouldn't really limit yourself to staying and working in either of those Provinces after you're done your studies.

Each school offers a program that is marketable really anywhere when you're done!

With that said, there were many jobs in Nova Scotia that were offered to prospective COGS grads, and I think a lot of N.S. natives ended up filling them. But students from outside of N.S. went back home or on to different places... or... ESRI...!!!